# with open('file', 'a' )as OUT: not writing all of the lines in the file

Tags: python

I have the code below to get some data from other files with some condition while iterates over data frame building a text file but the problem is that a lot of time the output text file not completed even with the last two lines in code that are out of iteration loop.
Also, sometimes the file is completed i don't know where the problem is.
note that:

With the same data frames and input files, sometimes i get the file completed and more times i get it missing lines.

I may run two python scripts at the same time, could it be the problem?

all code runs normally with no errors it's even run other code lines after that without any issue.

i tried with out.close and without it.

```
with open(IPATH+'\\'+ IP+'_XDSL_RECFG', 'a' )as OUT:
    OUT.write(f'environment inhibit-alarms\n')
    for i  in PORTS:
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if row[0]==i :
                if row[1] == 15 or row[1]=='NaN' :
                    SERVICE_PROFILE=12
                else:
                    SERVICE_PROFILE=int(row[1])
                if not row[2] == 5 or row[2]=='NaN' :
                    SPECTRUM_PROFILE=4
                else:
                    SPECTRUM_PROFILE=5
                if row[3] == 'rtx-profile':
                    RTX_PROFILE=('rtx-profile %s'%int(row[4]))
                else:
                    RTX_PROFILE=('no rtx-profile')
                if row[5]=='NaN':
                    OUTTER_VLAN=480
                    INNER_VLAN=PVID[i] # type: ignore
                else:
                    if row[5] <=1722 and row[5] >=1701 :
                        OUTTER_VLAN=int(row[5])
                        INNER_VLAN=int(row[6])
                    else:
                        OUTTER_VLAN=480
                        INNER_VLAN=PVID[i] # type: ignore
                OUT.write('configure xdsl line %s no service-profile no spectrum-profile no transfer-mode no auto-switch no admin-up\n' % (i))
                OUT.write('configure xdsl line %s service-profile %s spectrum-profile 1 transfer-mode atm\n' % (i,SERVICE_PROFILE))
                OUT.write('configure atm pvc %s:0:35\n' % (i))
                OUT.write('configure bridge port %s:0:35 max-unicast-mac 4\n' % (i))
                OUT.write('configure bridge port %s:0:35 vlan-id %s vlan-scope local network-vlan stacked:%s:%s\n' % (i,INNER_VLAN,OUTTER_VLAN,INNER_VLAN))
                OUT.write('configure bridge port %s:0:35 pvid stacked:%s:%s\n' % (i,OUTTER_VLAN,INNER_VLAN))
                OUT.write('configure xdsl line %s auto-switch\n' % (i))
                OUT.write('configure xdsl line %s admin-up\n' % (i))
                OUT.write('configure xdsl line %s no admin-up\n' % (i))
                OUT.write(f'sleep 3\n')
                OUT.write('configure xdsl line %s service-profile %s spectrum-profile %s %s transfer-mode ptm\n' % (i,SERVICE_PROFILE,SPECTRUM_PROFILE,RTX_PROFILE))
                OUT.write('configure bridge port %s max-unicast-mac 4\n' % (i))
                OUT.write('configure bridge port %s vlan-id %s vlan-scope local network-vlan stacked:%s:%s\n' % (i,INNER_VLAN,OUTTER_VLAN,INNER_VLAN))
                OUT.write('configure bridge port %s pvid stacked:%s:%s\n' % (i,OUTTER_VLAN,INNER_VLAN))
                OUT.write('configure xdsl line %s admin-up\n\n\n' % (i))
    OUT.write('## XDSL Reconfigure Done ##\n')
print('>>> XDSL_RECFG File Created.')
```

Comment: _I may run two python scripts at the same time, could it be the problem?_ Yes, if both of the scripts write to the same file.

Comment: `OUT.close` This is wrong, for two reasons.  First, `close` is a function, so you need parentheses on the end to actually call it, like this `close()`.  But you don't need to call close at all, because the `with open` block closes it for you automatically.

Comment: I run two python scripts at the same time creating same file name with other data and in different paths

Comment: i also tried without OUT.close() and the same issue happened

Comment: You don't need `OUT.close()` at all.  Remove it.

Comment: Okay, so if the two scripts **don't** write to the same file, then that isn't the problem.

Comment: What lines, specifically, are missing from the file?

Comment: it supposed to write all lines in loop for each {i} but it stops some times in the middle at different lines and sometimes it didn't write any lines at output file although the code runs normally and ended with out errors

Comment: That code has 15 calls to `OUT.write()` inside the loop.  So you're saying that sometimes only five, or ten, or twelve lines are actually written, instead of the full 15?  That doesn't seem possible with this code...

Comment: Or are you saying that the loop iterates fewer times than you expected?

Comment: thats what happens, even the last two lines out of loop

Comment: there are 2 loops (ie. one nested one).  You have indexed `ports` with `i`....  so if `ports` misses numbers, then you will not write every time because the code checks for this: `row[0]==i`  ....  so maybe you can shorten the example for clarity. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i don't know, but as i said the last two lines out of iterate loop wasn't written also so i think for some kind of issue the write to OUT is stopped @JohnGordon

Comment: Assuming `if row[0]==i` is true in the innermost loop, this code should write all 15 lines.  There is nothing that would cause the code to write some of those 15 but then skip the rest.  If that is happening, it must be caused by other code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Also, why do you keep saying "the last two lines out of the loop?"  There is only ONE `write()` call after the loop, not two...

Comment: One answer might be that some other process, not this one, is overwriting that file...

Comment: sorry i have a sconed line in the orignal code @JohnGordon

Comment: "One answer might be that some other process, not this one, is overwriting that file... "  I think that is the problem but how can i check? , the all path is created when i run the script @JohnGordon

Comment: Change the filename that's written in this code, run it, then check the results in the new filename.